# How to install and config php-config to php-config7 for PHP7.0 on Ubuntu

Tags: php, ubuntu

I have installed PHP7.0 on Ubuntu, but when I run php-config, it requires me to install it, which I want to install a php-config7 instead of a php-config5.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I was also stuck there but this command helped me.

I am using ubuntu 14.04

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:ondrej/php
```

it will install required repo for the php7

now install php-dev libs

```
sudo apt-get install php7.0-dev
```

now it will replace your old php-config to new one

now php-config will point to php-config7.0

Comment: Thanks for replay. I did a complete reinstall on my testing machine. And now it was working well. My Ubuntu is 16.04.

Comment: Installing the `-dev` package was the key for me to update pear modules successfully. On Debian 9.9 `php7.0-dev` is included in the normal `apt` repos.